# Deserialise Part of a JSON response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm working with a RESTful JSON API, and am attempting to deserialize PART of a JSON response message using Newtonsoft's JSON.Net framework.

Basically, the response JSON message I receive back includes header information as well as an array of items(Cards). When I try to deserialize to a list of cards, a .JsonSerializationException is thrown.

I'm almost certain it is because the `.DeserializeObject` method is tripping up on the header info. To test the theory, I 'massaged' the JSON response message & removed the header info; saved the remaining JSON as a string & passed it to the Deserialize method, & it worked!

**My question is** - is it possible to pass the `.DeserializeObject` method a parameter & force it to ONL deserialize the data component of the JSON response?

**The code:**

```
    public List<Cards.CardResponse> GetByUserToken(string UserToken)
    {
        string requestUrl = URL + "/user/" + UserToken;

        HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        List<Cards.CardResponse> ReturnCards = null;

        try
        {
            // Get JSON response message
            string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
            HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


            using (System.IO.StreamReader sreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                jsonResponse = sreader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // *** THE LINE BELOW THROWS THE ERROR:
            ReturnCards = (List<Cards.CardResponse>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, typeof(List<Cards.CardResponse>));**

            return ReturnCards;
```

**The Error Message:**

An unhandled exception of type '`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExpenseWorks.Marqeta.Cards+CardResponse]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

**The Raw JSON:**

I've also included the raw JSON Response - basically, I want to figure out how to only deserialize from 'data' onwards:

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "start_index": 0,
    "end_index": 4,
    "is_more": true,
    "data": [{
        "token": "9bd70529-f84a-406e-ad68-eabf69af690f",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "7281",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    },
    {
        "token": "0ec53aef-768d-4499-a661-9e26172b8369",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "5216",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    },
    {
        "token": "82c8b386 -f4b6-40d9-bee6-dd0a5b74d55b",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "6640",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    },
    {
        "token": "1181f23d-b464-4af2-95d9-8b8f48c4d6a8",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "3390",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    },
    {
        "token": "21870467-b059-472e-a130-938356ff1f4a",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "7387",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize it to a JObject first and then extract the part that you want:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var partialJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json["data"]);
var yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(partialJsonString );
```

However, it's quite trivial to create classes for everything:

```
public class ReplyRoot
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int start_index { get; set; }
    public int end_index { get; set; }
    public int is_more { get; set; }
    public DataEntry[] data { get; set; }
}

public class DataEntry
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    // [.. all properties ..]
}

var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReplyRoot>(jsonString);
```

Comment: you could also use "dynamic" to parse OR use attributes upon deserialization to ignore what you dont want

Comment: Brilliant - THANK YOU! Deserializing to a JObject looks like the best solution for us; we won't have to add the header fields to our existing classes. again - THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new class to hold the whole JSON object

```
public class CardResponseWrapper
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int startIndex { get; set; }
    public int endIndex { get; set; }
    public bool is_more { get; set; }

    public List<Cards.CardResponse> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then cast the result of the request to this object:

```
var result = (CardResponseWrapper)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, typeof(CardResponseWrapper));
```

Here is your json formatted:

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "start_index": 0,
    "end_index": 4,
    "is_more": true,
    "data": [{
        "token": "9bd70529-f84a-406e-ad68-eabf69af690f",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "7281",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }, {
        "token": "0ec53aef-768d-4499-a661-9e26172b8369",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "5216",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }, {
        "token": "82c8b386 -f4b6-40d9-bee6-dd0a5b74d55b",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "6640",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }, {
        "token": "1181f23d-b464-4af2-95d9-8b8f48c4d6a8",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "3390",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }, {
        "token": "21870467-b059-472e-a130-938356ff1f4a",
        "pan": "******______****",
        "expiration": "0219",
        "state": "UNACTIVATED",
        "user_token": "2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38",
        "card_product_token": "dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52",
        "last_four": "7387",
        "pin_is_set": false,
        "state_reason": "New card",
        "fulfillment_status": "ISSUED"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is your Json:

```
{
    \n\"count\": 5,
    \n\"start_index\": 0,
    \n\"end_index\": 4,
    \n\"is_more\": true,
    \n\"data\": [
        {
            \n\"token\": \"9bd70529-f84a-406e-ad68-eabf69af690f\",
            \n\"pan\": \"******______****\",
            \n\"expiration\": \"0219\",
            \n\"state\": \"UNACTIVATED\",
            \n\"user_token\": \"2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38\",
            \n\"card_product_token\": \"dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52\",
            \n\"last_four\": \"7281\",
            \n\"pin_is_set\": false,
            \n\"state_reason\": \"Newcard\",
            \n\"fulfillment_status\": \"ISSUED\"\n
        },
        {
            \n\"token\": \"0ec53aef-768d-4499-a661-9e26172b8369\",
            \n\"pan\": \"******______****\",
            \n\"expiration\": \"0219\",
            \n\"state\": \"UNACTIVATED\",
            \n\"user_token\": \"2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38\",
            \n\"card_product_token\": \"dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52\",
            \n\"last_four\": \"5216\",
            \n\"pin_is_set\": false,
            \n\"state_reason\": \"Newcard\",
            \n\"fulfillment_status\": \"ISSUED\"\n
        },
        {
            \n\"token\": \"82c8b386-f4b6-40d9-bee6-dd0a5b74d55b\",
            \n\"pan\": \"******______****\",
            \n\"expiration\": \"0219\",
            \n\"state\": \"UNACTIVATED\",
            \n\"user_token\": \"2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38\",
            \n\"card_product_token\": \"dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52\",
            \n\"last_four\": \"6640\",
            \n\"pin_is_set\": false,
            \n\"state_reason\": \"Newcard\",
            \n\"fulfillment_status\": \"ISSUED\"\n
        },
        {
            \n\"token\": \"1181f23d-b464-4af2-95d9-8b8f48c4d6a8\",
            \n\"pan\": \"******______****\",
            \n\"expiration\": \"0219\",
            \n\"state\": \"UNACTIVATED\",
            \n\"user_token\": \"2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38\",
            \n\"card_product_token\": \"dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52\",
            \n\"last_four\": \"3390\",
            \n\"pin_is_set\": false,
            \n\"state_reason\": \"Newcard\",
            \n\"fulfillment_status\": \"ISSUED\"\n
        },
        {
            \n\"token\": \"21870467-b059-472e-a130-938356ff1f4a\",
            \n\"pan\": \"******______****\",
            \n\"expiration\": \"0219\",
            \n\"state\": \"UNACTIVATED\",
            \n\"user_token\": \"2dea06b1-9fc8-423c-bb5b-b733ec895b38\",
            \n\"card_product_token\": \"dfd110cf-a833-4b21-b7c1-b3bc62b97c52\",
            \n\"last_four\": \"7387\",
            \n\"pin_is_set\": false,
            \n\"state_reason\": \"Newcard\",
            \n\"fulfillment_status\": \"ISSUED\"\n
        }
    ]\n
}
```

This is not a valid json to parse.
You can verificate this in: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment, sorry. Also, if think that is a valid answer.

Comment: It's obvious that there are escaped characters in the string. If you remove them it's valid JSON. Check for yourself, I've unescaped the JSON in his answer.